What actually happens when we put conditions without [] (brackets) in if else block in a bash script?
final=''
if [ $final ]; then echo "final"; else echo "not final"; fi;

Look at this code above. How would it apply and why, if I remove the brackets in the if block?
How does it evaluate the condition in that situation?
Below is how I was trying to write the condition. I actually forgot the syntax at that point. It prints final in the console. At that time I was expecting it to print not final. (I guess I somewhere read that in bash conditions, empty strings evaluate to false). I knew there is something wrong in the syntax though there was no error.
if $final; then printf "final"; else printf "not final"; fi;

Then I wrapped it around brackets. Now it outputs the opposite. not final.
The not of these these statements also give output without any error. Now I can't understand anything.
 if [ $final ]; then printf "final"; else printf "not final"; fi;

Output: not final .
if ! $final; then printf "final"; else printf "not final"; fi;

Output: not final
if [ ! $final ]; then printf "final"; else printf "not final"; fi;

Output: final .
I am totally confused!
I am running these in git-bash in windows.

The answer from the question Checking the success of a command in a bash `if [ .. ]` statement is not a valid answer of my question because I was trying to understand what happens when I omit the [ brackets in an if statement, particularly when dealing with an empty string.
The post said that if bracketts are removed then if block will run it as a command, other than testing it. But $final evaluates to an empty string. If I try to run empty strings in the commandline it gives error which it didn't give inside if block.
$ ''
-bash: : command not found

$ ! ''
-bash: : command not found

However, the answer did explain the role of [ in bash scripts and how it works as an alias for test. But, it did not directly clarify behavior of empty strings or direct command evaluation.
I read that answer, and my confusion was not cleared that is why I posted it here. My confusion only increased when I did some more research and read the post Why 0 is true but false is 1 in the shell?

Some comments from the staging ground had to do with using https://www.shellcheck.net/ to get rid of the most obvious traps. Did you try it?

My comment was that it might be closely related to Checking the success of a command in a bash if [ .. ] statement

I didn't know about shellcheck.net before. Yes, I tried to put the code in there. Says, "No issue detected".

It should have complained about not quoting the variable in if [ $final ]

See When are square brackets required in a Bash if statement?.  You also need to know that the command $final does nothing and produces good (0) status ($?) if $final expands to the empty string.

I'm not following what was wrong with closing the SG post as a dupe.  Now we have a question on the main site that, as far as I can tell, is a dupe.

This question is similar to: Checking the success of a command in a bash `if [ .. ]` statement. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This may be tangential, but because false and true are commands, you can do things like final=false; if $final; then; echo yes; fi. This is how I deal with booleans in my scripts.

In Bash, using if will simply run a command, and depending on the exit status of that command, it will run the code in the if block, otherwise the else block.
An if statement in its most basic form:
if some_command; then
    echo "some_command success: exit status = 0"
else
    echo "some_command failure: exit status = $?"
fi

In Unix sh and Bash, [ is an actual command (a shell built-in).
You can get help on it by using: help [
The [ command is used for boolean comparisons, such as:
if [ 4 -eq 4 ]; then echo "equal by math"; fi
if [ 9 -ge 7 ]; then echo "greater-than-or-equal-to"; fi
if [ "text-a" == "text-a" ]; then echo "equal by string comparison"; fi
if [ "text-a" != "text-b" ]; then echo "not equal by string comparison"; fi

Any command can have the exit status inverted using a ! before it, such as:
if ! some_command; then echo "some_command failed"; fi
if ! [ 3 -eq 4 ]; then echo "not (3 equals 4)"; fi

In addition, the [ command lets you use ! inside the square brackets to invert the boolean result:
if [ ! 3 -eq 4 ]; then echo "not (3 equals 4)"; fi

The result will be the same whether it's inside the [, or to the left of the [, but the logic to arrive at the result is different.
Please Note: There must be a space after the ! to avoid initiating history expansion.  This searches your typed in commands looking for a previous command that starts with whatever is after the !.  For example !rs would expand to your last entered command beginning with the letters rs, such as: rsync some options here.
In your code:
if [ $final ]; then
    echo "final"
else
    echo "not final"
fi

You are not quoting your $final variable, which is very risky behaviour.  If your variable is empty, or has special characters in it (such as spaces, ], -eq, etc.), this can break your if command.  Just remember that variables will be expanded to their values before the command is executed.  Always quote your variables inside [, like this:
if [ "$final" ]; then

Bash also has another extension, [[, which is not a part of Unix sh.  It operates the same as [, except that within [[ you can safely use variables without quoting them, such as:
if [[ $final -eq 7 ]]; then

In your case of removing the [ from the if statement:
if $final; then
    printf "final"
else
    printf "not final"
fi

The variable $final will be expanded before the if statement runs, so it will actually run a command of whatever text is stored in the $final variable.
For example:
final="ls -Alh /var"
if $final; then ...; fi

final="doesnt_exist"
if $final; then ...; fi

Then it would expand to:
if ls -Alh /var; then ...; fi
if doesnt_exist; then ...; fi

And finally, in regards to if [ $final ]; then when $final is empty, it would first expand to this:
if [ ]; then

On older versions of Bash this would produce an error for me, but it seems on my current v5.0.17 it no longer throws an error, it just silently fails.
That covers all of your questions.
But for a bonus, the if statement is actually not necessary in Bash.  There are also && and || which tell the shell to run commands on success or failure of a command, such as:
some_command && echo "success" || echo "failure"

This only allows you to run a single command after && or ||, otherwise it wouldn't be clear which command the failure or success applied to.
You can string together success chains like this:
some_command && another_one && third && final || echo "one of the commands failed"

Or you can use braces to include multiple commands on success or failure, such as:
some_command && { echo "success"; command_2; } || { echo "failure"; command_3; }

I often use this last method in my coding for printing out error messages and quitting, such as:
My_Installer -o "$Install_Dir" || {

    printf "PROBLEM: Failed to copy files to %s.\n\n" "$Install_Dir"
    printf "Quitting.\n\n"
    exit 1

}

Have fun with Bash, hope this helps!

if is followed by a (possibly compound) command to execute. It tests the success or failure of that command, by checking whether the exit status was 0 (success) or non-zero (failure).
The brackets are actually a command to execute, not part of the if command syntax (they're not like the parentheses in languages like C). [ is equivalent to the test command.
So when you write
if $final

it will execute the contents of $final as a command. If $final is empty, it executes an empty command. This is considered successful, so the then block is executed. If you first do
final=something

and then do
if $final

you'll get an error saying that something can't be found. This is a failure, so the else block will be executed.
On the other hand, when you write
if [ "$final" ]

it's executing test "$final". The test command just checks whether its argument is empty or not, and sets its exit status accordingly.

actually, if takes a compound-list. Consider: if date; echo hello; false; then echo ok; else echo no; fi

I've added the "compound" qualifier. I don't think most would understand the concept of "compound-list", it's a technical term that only appears in the documentation, no one actually uses it when talking about command lines.

true, and it can lead to interesting bugs. but worth knowing about, since only the exit status of the final command in the list is checked. used in while loops, it allows for interesting control flow

But for the purpose of understanding brackets vs no brackets, mostly irrelevant.

(enable -n [; command -V [) this could help realize [ is just /bin/[ (other than builtin)

@DiegoTorresMilano Surprisingly, /usr/bin/[ is not a link to /usr/bin/test on my Debian Linux, but they're hard links on MacOS.

@jhnc Interesting.  I've never seen multiple commands appearing before the then like that... and I've looked at a whole lot of scripts.  If it only uses the final command, probably not useful.  If I were trying to do something similar, I would probably stick the multiple commands in a function and do if my_function.  In the function I would return different exit codes for each command that could fail.  command1 || return 1; command2 || return 2, etc.

@Raven I think the main usefulness is in avoiding code duplication. if you have some initialisation that also happens after every iteration, you can write while init; test; do stuff; done instead of init; while test; do stuff; init; done

@Raven a possibly more useful special case of the general case above is "at least once" control flow which is common enough that some other languages provide a separate do {action} while (test) syntax. In sh it can be while action; test; do :; done

@jhnc Note that it makes more sense for while than if, but the syntax is the same for both because there's no reason not to. I can't think of any difference between cmd1; if cmd2; then ... and if cmd1; cmd2; then ...

Actually, they would be different if you do set -e. The first will stop immediately if cmd1 fails, the second executes both cmd1 and cmd2 in a context that ignores set -e.

good point. I forgot we were talking about if. I can't say I've ever wanted to use if with a compound_list.
